# Issue in establishing local movement system

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have managed to find out a good 3d rendering engine working in p5.js, and am now working on local movement. I have tried using trig to move the player in the correct directions, and the correct amount. for some reason, this doesn't seem to work, and i really have no idea what is going on. sorry for the poor commenting and somewhat ambiguous code, most of it isnt mine. Does anyone have any advice to get this working? thanks

```
var cam2;
var img = [];
var carousel;
var lookangle = 0;
var quadrant = 0;
var adjustedlookangle = 0;


function cameraFPS() {
  this.controllable = true;

  this.speed = 3;
  this.sensitivity = 2;
  this.friction = 0.75;

  this.position = createVector(0, 0, 0);
  this.velocity = createVector(0, 0, 0);

  this.pan = 0; // titta vänster, höger
  this.tilt = 0; // up and down
  this.y = createVector(0, 1, 0);
  this.x = createVector(1, 0, 0);
  this.z = createVector(0, 0, 1);
  this.center;

  this.mouse;
  this.prevMouse;

  this.draw = function() {
    perspective(60 / 180 * PI, width/height, 0.01, 1000);

    if(!this.controllable) return;

    this.mouse = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.prevMouse == null) this.prevMouse = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);

    var w = windowWidth;
    var h = windowHeight;

    if (this.mouse.x < 1 && (this.mouse.x - this.prevMouse.x) < 0){
            this.mouse.x = w-2;
            this.prevMouse.x = w-2;
        }
        if (this.mouse.x > w-2 && (this.mouse.x - this.prevMouse.x) > 0){
            this.mouse.x = 2;
            this.prevMouse.x = 2;
        }

        if (this.mouse.y < 1 && (this.mouse.y - this.prevMouse.y) < 0){
            this.mouse.y = h-2;
            this.prevMouse.y = h-2;
        }

        if (this.mouse.y > h-1 && (this.mouse.y - this.prevMouse.y) > 0){
            this.mouse.y = 2;
            this.prevMouse.y = 2;
        }

    this.pan = map(this.mouse.x - this.prevMouse.x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI) * this.sensitivity;
        this.tilt = map(this.mouse.y - this.prevMouse.y, 0, height, 0, PI) * this.sensitivity;
        this.tilt = constrain(this.tilt, -PI/2.01, PI/2.01);

    if (this.tilt == PI/2) tilt += 0.001;

    this.z = createVector(cos(this.pan), tan(this.tilt), sin(this.pan));
    this.z.normalize(this.z);
    this.x = createVector(cos(this.pan - PI/2), 0, sin(this.pan - PI/2));

    this.prevMouse = createVector(this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y);

    if (keyIsDown(65)) this.velocity.add(p5.Vector.mult(this.x, this.speed));
        if (keyIsDown(68)) this.velocity.sub(p5.Vector.mult(this.x, this.speed));
        if (keyIsDown(87)) this.velocity.add(p5.Vector.mult(this.z, this.speed));
        if (keyIsDown(83)) this.velocity.sub(p5.Vector.mult(this.z, this.speed));
        if (keyIsDown(81)) this.velocity.add(p5.Vector.mult(this.y, this.speed));
        if (keyIsDown(69)) this.velocity.sub(p5.Vector.mult(this.y, this.speed));

    this.velocity.mult(this.friction);
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    this.center = p5.Vector.add(this.position, this.z);

    camera(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.position.z);
    //rotateX(this.center.y);
    //rotateY(this.center.x);
    //rotateZ(this.center.z);

  }

}



function navCamera() {
  //Camera position and rotation
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.z = 0;
  this.xRotation = 0;
  this.yRotation = 0;

  //Properties for rotating camera with mouse
  this.lastMouseX = width / 2;
  this.lastMouseY = height / 2;
  this.beganMouseY = 0;
  this.beganMouseX = 0;

  this.update = function() {
    this.checkInput();

    //camera(this.x, this.y, this.z);
    //translate(-this.x, -this.y, -this.z)

    translate(0, 0, 1000);
    rotateY(-PI/2 + (PI)  * (this.xRotation / width));
    //rotateX(-PI/2 + (PI)  * (this.yRotation / height));
    translate(-cam.x, -cam.y, -cam.z)
    }

  this.checkInput = function() {
    //key input
    if(keyIsDown(87)) { // W

      if (quadrant == 1) {

       this.x -= Math.cos(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.z -= Math.sin(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      } else if (quadrant == 2) {

          this.z += Math.cos(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.x -= Math.sin(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
    } else if (quadrant == 3) {
          this.x -= Math.cos(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.z -= Math.sin(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
    } else if (quadrant == 4) {
          this.x -= Math.cos(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.z -= Math.sin(adjustedlookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
    }



    }
    if(keyIsDown(83)) { //S
      this.x += Math.cos(lookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.z += Math.sin(lookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
    }
    if(keyIsDown(65)) { //A
      this.z += Math.cos(lookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.x -= Math.sin(lookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
    }
    if(keyIsDown(68)) { //D
      this.z -= Math.cos(lookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
      this.x += Math.sin(lookangle * (Math.PI / 180))
    }

    //Calculate mouse movement while pressed
    this.xRotation = this.lastMouseX;
    this.yRotation = this.lastMouseY;

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      var deltaX = mouseX - this.beganMouseX;
      this.xRotation += deltaX;
      var deltaY = mouseY - this.beganMouseY;
      this.yRotation += deltaY;
       print (this.xRotation / 10)


      //get lookangle in degrees

      lookangle = (this.xRotation / 10 % 360)


      //discern quadrant
      if (lookangle < 90) {
        quadrant = 1;


      }else if (lookangle < 180) {
        quadrant = 2;


      }else if (lookangle < 270) {
        quadrant = 3;

      }else if (lookangle < 360) {
        quadrant = 4;


      }
      print (quadrant)
      adjustedlookangle = (lookangle - 90 * (quadrant - 1))
      //to make radian (Math.PI / 180)

    }
  }

  this.onMouseRelease = function() {
    var deltaX = mouseX - this.beganMouseX;
    var deltaY = mouseY - this.beganMouseY;
    this.lastMouseX += deltaX;
    this.lastMouseY += deltaY;
  }

  this.onMousePress = function() {
    this.beganMouseX = mouseX;
    this.beganMouseY = mouseY;
  }

}





function preload() {
  img.push(loadImage('assets/nature.jpg'));
  img.push(loadImage('assets/nature2.jpg'));
  //img.push(loadImage('assets/wall.jpg'));
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);

  cam = new navCamera();
  cam2 = new cameraFPS();
  carousel = new carousel();
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  cam.update();
  //cam2.draw();
  carousel.update();

  //texture(img[2]);
  //fill(255, 255, 0);
  //box(5000, 10, 5000);
}

function carousel() {
  // setup 8 boxes in a caraousel

  this.total = 4;
  this.radius = 200;

  this.update = function() {
    this.centerX = 0;
    this.centerY = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.total; i++) {
      var x = (Math.cos(i / this.total * TWO_PI) * this.radius),
          z = (Math.sin(i / this.total * TWO_PI) * this.radius),
          y = 0;

      push();
      translate(x, y, z);
      fill(100, 50, (255 / 8) * i);
      texture(img[i % 2]);
      rotateY(-QUARTER_PI * (i + 2));
      box(100, 100, 100);
      pop();
    }
  }
}

function mouseReleased() {
  cam.onMouseRelease();
}

function mousePressed() {
  cam.onMousePress();
}
```

Comment: In what sense does this not work? Player not moving?

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate things. The variables `lookangle`, `quadrant` and `adjustedlookangle` are not needed at all.

You need attributes for the location and orientation:

```ls
function navCamera() {
    //Camera position and rotation
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.z = 0;
    this.xRotation = 0; // rotation around x axis in radians
    this.yRotation = 0; // rotation around y axis in radians

    // [...]
```

And attributes for the begin of the mouse movement and the current rotation angles when the moused is dragged:

```ls
function navCamera() {
    // [...]

    this.xCurrentRotation = 0; // current (dragged) rotation around x axis in radians 
    this.yCurrentRotation = 0; // current (dragged) rotation around y axis in radians
    this.beganMouseX = 0;      // x start of mouse drag
    this.beganMouseY = 0;      // y start of mouse drag

    // [...]
}
```

Use the parameters to set the view by [`camera`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/camera). e.g:

```ls
function navCamera() {
    // [...]

    this.update = function() {

        this.checkInput();

        let sinay = Math.sin(this.yCurrentRotation);
        let cosay = Math.cos(this.yCurrentRotation); 
        let sinax = Math.sin(this.xCurrentRotation);
        let cosax = Math.cos(this.xCurrentRotation); 
        resetMatrix(); 
        camera(this.x, this.y, this.z, cosax*sinay+this.x, sinax+this.y, cosax*cosay+this.z, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

The mouse events update the `this.xRotation` respectively `this.yRotation`:

```ls
function navCamera() {
    // [...]

    this.onMousePress = function() {
        this.beganMouseX = mouseX;
        this.beganMouseY = mouseY;
    }

    this.onMouseRelease = function() {
        this.yRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseX - this.beganMouseX) / width;
        this.xRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseY - this.beganMouseY) / height;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

In `navCamera` the current angles and the camera position is set:

```ls
function navCamera() {
    // [...]

    this.checkInput = function() {

        this.yCurrentRotation = this.yRotation;
        this.xCurrentRotation = this.xRotation;
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            this.yCurrentRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseX - this.beganMouseX) / width;
            this.xCurrentRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseY - this.beganMouseY) / height;
        }

        let sina = Math.sin(this.yCurrentRotation);
        let cosa = Math.cos(this.yCurrentRotation);

        //key input
        if(keyIsDown(87)) { // W
            this.x += sina; this.z += cosa;
        }
        if(keyIsDown(83)) { //S
            this.x -= sina; this.z -= cosa;
        }
        if(keyIsDown(65)) { //A
            this.z -= sina; this.x += cosa;
        }
        if(keyIsDown(68)) { //D
            this.z += sina; this.x -= cosa;
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

See the example:

```js
var img = [];
var carousel;

function navCamera() {
    //Camera position and rotation
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.z = 0;
    this.xRotation = 0; // rotation around x axis in radians
    this.yRotation = 0; // rotation around y axis in radians
    
    this.xCurrentRotation = 0; // current (dragged) rotation around x axis in radians 
    this.yCurrentRotation = 0; // current (dragged) rotation around y axis in radians
    this.beganMouseX = 0;      // x start of mouse drag
    this.beganMouseY = 0;      // y start of mouse drag

    this.update = function() {
        
        this.checkInput();

        let sinay = Math.sin(this.yCurrentRotation);
        let cosay = Math.cos(this.yCurrentRotation); 
        let sinax = Math.sin(this.xCurrentRotation);
        let cosax = Math.cos(this.xCurrentRotation); 
        resetMatrix(); 
        camera(this.x, this.y, this.z, cosax*sinay+this.x, sinax+this.y, cosax*cosay+this.z, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }

    this.checkInput = function() {

        this.yCurrentRotation = this.yRotation;
        this.xCurrentRotation = this.xRotation;
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            this.yCurrentRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseX - this.beganMouseX) / width;
            this.xCurrentRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseY - this.beganMouseY) / height;
        }

        let sina = Math.sin(this.yCurrentRotation);
        let cosa = Math.cos(this.yCurrentRotation);

        //key input
        if(keyIsDown(87)) { // W
            this.x += sina; this.z += cosa;
        }
        if(keyIsDown(83)) { //S
            this.x -= sina; this.z -= cosa;
        }
        if(keyIsDown(65)) { //A
            this.z -= sina; this.x += cosa;
        }
        if(keyIsDown(68)) { //D
            this.z += sina; this.x -= cosa;
        }
    }

    this.onMousePress = function() {
        this.beganMouseX = mouseX;
        this.beganMouseY = mouseY;
    }

    this.onMouseRelease = function() {
        this.yRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseX - this.beganMouseX) / width;
        this.xRotation -= PI/2 * (mouseY - this.beganMouseY) / height;
    }
}

function preload() {
  img.push(loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/test1_texture.bmp'));
  img.push(loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/tree.jpg'));
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);

    cam = new navCamera();
    carousel = new carousel();
}

function draw() {
    background(200);

    cam.update();
    carousel.update();
}

function carousel() {
  // setup 8 boxes in a caraousel

  this.total = 4;
  this.radius = 200;

  this.update = function() {
    this.centerX = 0;
    this.centerY = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.total; i++) {
      var x = (Math.cos(i / this.total * TWO_PI) * this.radius),
          z = (Math.sin(i / this.total * TWO_PI) * this.radius),
          y = 0;

      push();
      translate(x, y, z);
      fill(100, 50, (255 / 8) * i);
      texture(img[i % 2]);
      rotateY(-QUARTER_PI * (i + 2));
      box(100, 100, 100);
      pop();
    }
  }
}

function mouseReleased() {
  cam.onMouseRelease();
}

function mousePressed() {
  cam.onMousePress();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```